# Professional way of saying "without having to worry about"?

Tags: science

I am writing a scientific paper in which I am faced with writing a sentence like the following: "We can perform X without having to worry about the effects of Y". The phrase 'without having to worry about' doesn't seem very professional to me. One alternate way that comes to my mind is "We can perform X independently of the effects of Y". However it doesn't seem to convey the message strongly enough.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange ELU! Please provide more detailed information in your post. How are you wanting to use the phrase? What is the context?

Comment: Either "...without having to consider the effects of Y" or "...without having to take the effects of Y into consideration" would do the job

Comment: It would help tremendously if you could provide a concrete statement instead of speaking in term of X and Y.

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions:

> We can perform X without **concerning ourselves with** the effects of Y.

Or to remove any connotation:

> We can perform X without considering the effects of Y.
>
> We can perform X without regard to the effects of Y.
>
> We can perform X regardless of the effects of Y.

Comment: For our purposes, X can be considered to be independent from Y.

Answer (score 0):

*"in spite of the effects"* or or *"regardless of the effects"* of would probably do.
I would need more context than that for a more accurate alternative.

Answer (score 0):

We can perform X ***notwithstanding*** the effects of Y.

Answer (score 0):

"We may perform X without a need for concern about the effects of Y."

(Presumably you go on to explain why we may do that without concern.)